# How to read and combine multiple files into one dataframe in rstudio?

Tags: r

```
for (i in 1:length(all_files)) {file <- read_tsv(all_files[i], col_names = FALSE) %>% bind_rows()}
```

This code saves only the last file from the folder to dataframe file.. Also, this files doesn't have headers, so I used col_names = FALSE, but then I also need to skip some of the columns and rename others, so how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to read in and stack/append many files into one data.frame, I recommend using a list.  Read-in files one at a time, saving each data.frame as a list element (ie, the third file you read in is a data.frame stored in the third element of a list).  The package data.table then has a handy function that will stack them all for you.

Some template code:

```
# empty list to store each file as a data.frame when read-in
file_list <- vector(mode="list", length=length(all_files))

# loop over files, reading in one at a time
for(i in 1:length(all_files)) {
    file_list[[i]] <- read_tsv(all_files[i])
}

# stack all of the files using rbindlist() from package data.table
big_df <- rbindlist(file_list)
```